# Azure Blobstorage SAS Token Urls that decrypt data

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I am trying to implement a feature that pulls data from blob storage using an SAS Token on the URL. One of the issues that I am running into with this is that I have Server Side Encryption within the azure infrastructure so that files we are uploading to a blob container location become encrypted.

The current implementation we have for downloading these files doesn't currently use a SAS token and I am simple calling `DownloadTextAsync()` on the blob block reference. This is all well and good and produces a file that isn't encrypted upon download but this comes with a performance hit as the file depending on the size can take quite sometime to finish downloading and on my front-end can lead to an unfriendly user experience.

I can implement generating the SAS token and appending this to a uri that references the given blob but upon clicking this link or pasting it into a web browser the file that is downloaded is still encrypted. I've tried adding `SharedAccessBlobHeaders` to the `GetSharedAccessSignature` call as well specifying the `ContentDispostion`, `ContentType` and `ContentEncoding` and nothing appeared to download a file that wasn't encrypted.

Am I missing something, is there a way to have the SAS token to say to decrypt the file or is this not possible?

**EDIT:**

Added some code snippets of what I am doing around the blob store.

```
  
  //Method in a Factory Implementation
  public async Task<IBlobStore> CreateBlobStoreAsync(string containerName)
  {
    var storageAccount = AzureStorageCommon.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration.AzureStorageConnectionString);
    var cloudBlobClient = new AzureStorageBlob.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient(storageAccount.BlobStorageUri, storageAccount.Credentials, null);

      var keyVaultKeyResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver((KeyVaultClient) _keyVaultClient);
      var keyBundle = await _keyVaultClient.GetKeyAsync(_configuration.KeyVaultUri, _configuration.EncryptionKeyName);

      var key = await keyVaultKeyResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(keyBundle.KeyIdentifier.Identifier, CancellationToken.None);
      var policy = new AzureStorageBlob.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobEncryptionPolicy(key, keyVaultKeyResolver);
      cloudBlobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.EncryptionPolicy = policy;

    var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var blobStore = new AzureBlobStore(container, _logger);
    return blobStore;
  }


public async Task<string> GetImportJobSasUrl(string store, string name)
{
    var blobStore = await _blobStoreFactory.CreateBlobStoreAsync(store); //Method above
    var exists = await blobStore.ExistsAsync(name);
    if (!exists)
        return null;

    var fileSasUri = await blobStore.GetSasTokenUrlAsync(name);

    return fileSasUri;
} 


public async Task<string> GetSasTokenUrlAsync(string name)
{
    string sasUrl;
    try
    {
        await _container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var policy = new AzureStorageBlob.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            SharedAccessStartTime = currentTime,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = currentTime.AddHours(1),
            Permissions = AzureStorageBlob.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
        };

        var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, headers);
        sasUrl = $"{blob.Uri}{sasToken}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error getting SAS token URL from Azure Blob Storage. Name: {name}");
        throw;
    }
    return sasUrl;
}
```

Comment: Something is missing. Are you using SSE (server side encryption) or client-provided key encryption? With SSE the encryption should be transparent and you should get decrypted content independent of the way you access the content (DownloadTextAsync or SAS url). Btw SSE has negligible impact on performance / download speed, so I'd try to find the bottleneck somewhere else (when using client-provided key, that may be different)

Comment: Hi @Corey , Can you please edit the question and add the code how you generating SAS token and downloading file

Comment: @ShrutiJoshi-MT, I've added some snippets for how I am generating the tokens. Let me know if I need to be more specific but the use case it just being called from an API Endpoint that should be returning the url.